# Angular ReactiveForm formControl counter

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I try to build up a counter in Angular as a ReactiveForm to generate a JSON string which I want to send to another form to continue a purchase process.

My counter just working fine, but I don't get the value into the string without an input field. But I dont want to have there an input field for the user.

My code of the FormGroup looks like this at the moment:

```
<div formGroupName="ticket">
    <div class="row">
      <p>Adults</p>
      <i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" (click)="decrementAdult();"></i>
      <p formControlName="valueAdult" ngDefaultControl>{{counterValueAdult}}</p>
      <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" (click)="incrementAdult();"></i>
    </div>
    <div> ... same for children ... </div>
  </div>
```

In the request.component.ts file I have a FormGroup:

```
requestForm = new FormGroup({
  foo1: new FormControl(),
  foo2: new FormControl(),
  ticket: new FormGroup({
    valueAdult: new FormControl(),
    valueChildren: new FormControl()
  })
});
incrementAdult() {
  this.counterValueAdult +=1;
  if (this.counterValueAdult >= this.maxAdult)
    this.counterValueAdult = 4;
    this.requestForm.get('ticket.valueAdult').setValue = this.counterValueAdult;
}
decrementAdult() {
  this.counterValueAdult -=1;
  if (this.counterValueAdult <= this.minAdult)
    this.counterValueAdult = 1;
    this.requestForm.get('ticket.valueAdult').setValue = this.counterValueAdult;
}
```

At the end of the form I catch the input for improvement with:

```
 <p>{{ requestForm.value | json }}</p>
```

and get back: { "foo1": value, "foo2": value, "ticket": { "valueAdult": null, "valueChildren": null } }

Does anyone have an idea to get back the value between the parenthesis instead of null?

```
<p ... >{{...}}</p>
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you have and what you are trying to get. Could you explain a little more, or post more code?

Comment: add more description or code

Comment: I've added some more code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
ticket.get('valueAdult').value
```

Anyway, Why do you use a reactiveForm? You don't need it, just

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bla-bla',
  template: '<p>ticket.adults</p>'
})
export class HeroDetailComponent1 {
  ticket:any={"adults":3};
}
```

Comment: `ticket.get('valueAdult').value` is read-only. To patch its value, you should use `.setValue` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the value of valueAdult with the calculated value in the methods where you increment/decrement.

```
incrementAdult(){
  // as before
   this.requestForm.get('ticket').get('valueAdult').setValue = this.counterValueAdult;
   // or  this.requestForm.get('ticket.valueAdult').setValue = this.counterValueAdult;
}

decrementAdult(){
  // as before
   this.requestForm.get('ticket').get('valueAdult').setValue = this.counterValueAdult;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got what you mean and tried it out, but get now an error: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined. Here is my code of the increment method:

`get valueAdult() {
    return this.requestForm.get('ticket.valueAdult');
  }
  get valueChildren() {
    return this.requestForm.get('ticket.valueChildren');
  }`

`incrementAdult() {
    this.counterValueAdult +=1;
    if (this.counterValueAdult >= this.maxAdult)
      this.counterValueAdult = 4;
      this.ticket.get('valueAdult').setValue = this.counterValueAdult;
  }
decrementAdult() {  ...  }
`

Comment: Now my value get showed as NaN if i click first time on a button, but at least there are no more errors. I've also had to define counterValueAdult as a 'any' object, before I was working with a number.

Comment: Can you update you post with the code from the comment above, please. So I can see better were we are?

Comment: Here is the actual code: 
`incrementAdult() {
    this.counterValueAdult +=1;
    if (this.counterValueAdult >= this.maxAdult)
      this.counterValueAdult = 4;
    this.requestForm.get('ticket.valueAdult').setValue = this.counterValueAdult;
  }`

Comment: Please update the question post with the code above. Press 'edit' under the post and update the question

Comment: You have updated my answer and I had to reject. Update your question post, not mine please

Comment: Sorry, did not see that was on the way. Now I updated my original post and add the increment/decrement part.

Comment: You don't need formControlName="valueAdult" in <p> tag... In your form you don't have anything that needs formcontrols. You just neee 'plain' properties. What is the purpose of requestForm? Just to gather information? You can initantiate a new Object instead

Comment: something similar to airbnb, on the frontend is a request form on which the user should define where, when and how much persons. with this information he should be redirected to a identified provider where i need the information from the request form to define a dynamic form component